# How can I control volume with a PS4?

Tags: ps4

I have a PS4, which attaches to a monitor through hdmi.  The monitor then attaches to some speakers which have no volume controls.

I need to control volume, currently the only way is to navigate the monitor settings using its menu and brightness buttons.  This is absurd.

The monitor is CEC compliant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control), I can control it with my Mac and a CEC tool (https://github.com/the0neyouseek/MonitorControl).

I've already found that PS4's do not have a *volume control* built in.

Is there no plugin for this?  No plugin for standard CEC control?

Comment: Hmm, I just checked and Quick Menu indeed doesn't allow me to change volume when connected through HDMI

Comment: You cannot plug something directly into a monitor, because then you won't have more than two channels. Playing with two channels is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only CEC control known for the PS4 is to turn on/off the TV when the PS4 is turned on/off.

It doesn't appear to have volume control, or any other control.